# How can I find my CompanyKey.Id in Microsoft Dynamics GP

Tags: web-services, dynamics-gp

New to Microsoft Dynamics GP 2010. I am programming using the web services. Many of them require you to create a CompanyKey object and set its Id property. How can I figure out what my company Id is?

The guide doesn't seem to direct me nor does a Google search. I feel like this is such an easy question. I just really got thrown into the middle of this.

Answer (score 1):

like credentials , you must also know the company id.

if you want your user to dynamically switch company then you can use GetCompanyList method of web service to retrieve all the companies in your GP setup.
form the resultant array you can easily get company id.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CMPNYNAM, INTERID, CMPANYID
FROM DYNAMICS.dbo.SY01500

Comment: If you work with WCF service, you may not have access to DB